# Re-signed IPA from terminal Segmentation fault 11 error on OS Sierra 10.12

Tags: ios, swift, macos, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to resign the IPA file from terminal using the following command:

```
codesign -f -s "<Certificate name>" "Test.app";
```

It was working fine on my previous mac OS version. But after upgrading the mac os to Sierra 10.12 and Xcode to 8.0; I am getting this error if I try to sign the IPA from terminal.

I'm getting **Segmentation fault 11** error.

Any one can help? Advance Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

i have also such a segmentation fault with MacOS Sierra.
I was able to fix the Problem with adding timestamp=none parameter and 
use the SHA1 Fingerprint ID instead of the Certificate Name for the -s parameter

You can get the Fingerprint with:
security find-identity -p codesigning

then look for your name and use the very long ID value.
Change your command to:
codesign -f -s Fingerprint ID "Test.app" timestamp=none

regards